# Nearest "n" rolling join in R data table

Tags: r, join, data.table

With `data.table`, we can join a value in one data set with the nearest value in another by using `roll = "nearest"`. Some example data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c(15,101), id1 = c("x", "y"))
dt2 <- data.table(x = c(10,50,100,200), id2 = c("a","b","c","d"))
```

Using `roll = "nearest"`, I can join each 'x' in 'dt1' with the 'x' in dt2 which is nearest:

```
dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest", on = "x"]
#     x  id2 id1
# 1: 15    a   x
# 2: 101   c   y
```

E.g. for `x = 15` in 'dt1', the nearest `x` value in 'dt2' is `x = 10`, and we get the corresponding 'id2' which is `"a"`.

But what if instead of getting *one* nearest value, I want to get *n* nearest values? For example, if I want the *2* nearest x values, the result would be:

```
     x id2 id1  roll
1:  15   a   x   nr1
2:  15   b   x   nr2
3: 101   c   y   nr1
4: 101   b   y   nr2
```

("nr" stands for "nearest")

I want a general approach that I can apply to any "n" (e.g. 2 nearest points, 3 nearest points, etc).

---

**EDIT**
I wonder if it is possible to also apply this to multi columns join where the join will match on the preceding column before getting the nearest on the last join column. For example:

```
dt1 <- data.table(group=c(1,2), x=(c(15,101)), id1=c("x","y"))
dt2 <- data.table(group=c(1,2,2,3), x=c(10,50,100,200),id2=c("a","b","c","d"))
```

If I join `on=c("group","x")`, the join will first match on "group" and then get the nearest on "x", so I would expect the result to be something like:

```
     x  group id2 id1  roll
1:  15      1   a   x   nr1
2: 101      2   c   y   nr1
3: 101      2   b   y   nr2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something very raw (we go row by row):

```
n <- 2L
sen <- 1L:n
for (i in 1:nrow(dt1)) {
  set(dt1, i, j = "nearest", list(which(frank(abs(dt1$x[i] - dt2$x)) %in% sen)))
}
dt1[, .(id1, nearest = unlist(nearest)), by = x
    ][, id2 := dt2$id2[nearest]
      ][, roll := paste0("nr", frank(abs(dt2$x[nearest] - x))), by = x][]

#      x id1 nearest id2 roll
# 1:  15   x       1   a  nr1
# 2:  15   x       2   b  nr2
# 3: 101   y       2   b  nr2
# 4: 101   y       3   c  nr1
```

Slightly cleaner:

```
dt1[, 
    {
      nrank <- frank(abs(x - dt2$x), ties.method="first")
      nearest <- which(nrank %in% sen)
      .(x = x, id2 = dt2$id2[nearest], roll = paste0("nr", nrank[nearest]))
    }, 
    by = id1] # assumes unique ids.
```

Data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = c(15, 101), id1 = c("x", "y"))
dt2 <- data.table(x = c(10, 50, 100, 200), id2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

---

**EDIT** (as suggested/written by OP)
Joining with multiple keys:

```
dt1[, 
    {
      g <- group
      dt_tmp <- dt2[dt2$group == g]
      nrank <- frank(abs(x - dt_tmp$x), ties.method="first")
      nearest <- which(nrank %in% sen)
      .(x = x, id2 = dt_tmp$id2[nearest], roll = paste0("nr", nrank[nearest]))
    }, 
    by = id1]
```

Comment: I would suggest to use frank(abs(x - dt2$x), ties.method="first") to avoid the default of "average"

Comment: Hi again @sindri_baldur! I was playing around with your nice solution to fully understand it, and now I have a question: does the `by = id1` mean that it depends on id1 being a _unique row id_? E.g. try a dt1 with several identical id1: `dt1 = data.table(x = c(1L, 4L), id1 = c("x", "x"))`; `dt2 = data.table(x = 2:3, id2 = 2:3)`. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik Yes. It assumes unique ids. Was mainly focused on having fun solving the problem at hand - haven't thought about the general problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sindri_baldur! I also thought it was a really fun problem to struggle with. I was just poking around with all the  answers to try to learn some new tricks on the way, and happened to stumble over some things I didn't fully understand. Thanks again for taking your time to explain - it certainly makes your nice answer more valuable to future visitors :)

Answer (score 6):

**Edited** for corrected ordering.

I don't know that `roll=` is going to allow nearest-`n`, but here's a possible workaround:

```r
dt1[, id2 := lapply(x, function(z) { r <- head(order(abs(z - dt2$x)), n = 2); dt2[ r, .(id2, nr = order(r)) ]; }) ]
as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(dt1, id2))
#      x id1 id2 nr
# 1:  15   x   a  1
# 2:  15   x   b  2
# 3: 101   y   c  2
# 4: 101   y   b  1
```

(I'm using `tidyr::unnest` because I think it fits and works well here, and [data.table/#3672](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3672) is still open.)

---

Second batch of data:

```r
dt1 = data.table(x = c(1, 5, 7), id1 = c("x", "y", "z"))
dt2 = data.table(x = c(2, 5, 6, 10), id2 = c(2, 5, 6, 10))
dt1[, id2 := lapply(x, function(z) { r <- head(order(abs(z - dt2$x)), n = 2); dt2[ r, .(id2, nr = order(r)) ]; }) ]
as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(dt1, id2))
#    x id1 id2 nr
# 1: 1   x   2  1
# 2: 1   x   5  2
# 3: 5   y   5  1
# 4: 5   y   6  2
# 5: 7   z   6  2
# 6: 7   z   5  1
```

Comment: this works on a relatively small batch, but can be very slow when the data is huge

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option using rolling join **without an additional grouping key** (an improvement on my initial naive cross join idea):

```
#for differentiating rows from both data.tables
dt1[, ID := .I]
dt2[, rn := .I]

#perform rolling join to find closest and 
#then retrieve the +-n rows around that index from dt2
n <- 2L
adjacent <- dt2[dt1, on=.(x), roll="nearest", nomatch=0L, by=.EACHI,
    c(.(ID=ID, id1=i.id1, val=i.x), dt2[unique(pmin(pmax(0L, seq(x.rn-n, x.rn+n, by=1L)), .N))])][,
        (1L) := NULL]

#extract nth nearest
adjacent[order(abs(val-x)), head(.SD, n), keyby=ID]
```

output:

```
   ID id1 val   x id2 rn
1:  1   x  15  10   a  1
2:  1   x  15  50   b  2
3:  2   y 101 100   c  3
4:  2   y 101  50   b  2
```

And using Henrik's dataset:

```
dt1 = data.table(x = c(1, 5, 7), id1 = c("x", "y", "z"))
dt2 = data.table(x = c(2, 5, 6, 10), id2 = c(2, 5, 6, 10))
```

output:

```
   ID id1 val x id2 rn
1:  1   x   1 2   2  1
2:  1   x   1 5   5  2
3:  2   y   5 5   5  2
4:  2   y   5 6   6  3
5:  3   z   7 6   6  3
6:  3   z   7 5   5  2
```

And also Henrik's 2nd dataset:

```
dt1 = data.table(x = 3L, id1="x")
dt2 = data.table(x = 1:2, id2=c("a","b"))
```

output:

```
   ID id1 val x id2 rn
1:  1   x   3 2   b  2
2:  1   x   3 1   a  1
```

---

And also **joining on an additional grouping key**:

```
dt2[, rn := .I]

#perform rolling join to find closest and
#then retrieve the +-n rows around that index from dt2
n <- 2L
adjacent <- dt2[dt1, on=.(group, x), roll="nearest", by=.EACHI, {
        xrn <- unique(pmax(0L, seq(x.rn-n, x.rn+n, by=1L)), .N)
        c(.(id1=id1, x1=i.x),
            dt2[.(group=i.group, rn=xrn), on=.(group, rn), nomatch=0L])
    }][, (1L:2L) := NULL]

#extract nth nearest
adjacent[order(abs(x1-x)), head(.SD, 2L), keyby=id1] #use id1 to identify rows if its unique, otherwise create ID column like prev section
```

output:

```
   id1  x1 group   x id2 rn
1:   x  15     1  10   a  1
2:   y 101     2 100   c  3
3:   y 101     2  50   b  2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(group=c(1,2), x=(c(15,101)), id1=c("x","y"))
dt2 <- data.table(group=c(1,2,2,3), x=c(10,50,100,200), id2=c("a","b","c","d"))
```

Comment: can I use this with multiple join columns? like in data.table, I can specify on=c("group", "x") so the join will first match by "group" and then roll to the nearest x. I just wonder if this works with your solution.

Comment: this doesn't work when I have:
dt1 <- data.table(group=c(1,2), x=(c(15,101)), id1=c("x","y"))   
dt2 <- data.table(group=c(1,2,2,3), x=c(10,50,100,200), id2=c("a","b","c","d"))
the first group in dt1 is joined with the second group in dt2

Comment: @Algorithman thanks. I have moved the inner join inside j to address rows cutting across groups

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for you solution, I really liked it! I was playing with really simple data sets to fully understand it and stumbled over what may be an unexpected result: when an x value in dt1 is larger than the largest value in dt2, it seems to select the same nearest value twice. E.g. `dt1 = data.table(x = 3L)`; `dt2 = data.table(x = 1:2)`. Here I would expect 3 to first match to with 2 and then to 1. However, it seems like it matches to 2 twice. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik, its because of duplication of row indices after truncating the row indices. I have updated the code. thanks so much for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

A *k nearest neighbour* alternative using `nabor::knn`:

```
library(nabor)
k = 2L
dt1[ , {
  kn = knn(dt2$x2, x, k)
  c(.SD[rep(seq.int(.N), k)],
    dt2[as.vector(kn$nn.idx),
        .(x2 = x, id2, nr = rep(seq.int(k), each = dt1[ ,.N]))]) 
}]
#      x id1  x2 id2 nr
# 1:  15   x  10   a  1
# 2: 101   y 100   c  1
# 3:  15   x  50   b  2
# 4: 101   y  50   b  2
```

In common with the answers by @sindri_baldur and @r2evans, an actual join (`on =` ) is not performed, we "only" do something in `j`.

---

#### Timings

On data of rather modest size (`nrow(dt1)`: 1000; `nrow(dt2)`: 10000), *knn* seems faster:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
#   henrik    8.09383   10.19823   10.54504   10.2835   11.00029   13.72737    20
# chinsoon 2140.48116 2154.15559 2176.94620 2171.5824 2192.54536 2254.20244    20
#  r2evans 4496.68625 4562.03011 4677.35214 4680.0699 4751.35237 4935.10655    20
#   sindri 4194.93867 4397.76060 4406.29278 4402.7913 4432.76463 4490.82789    20
```

[image]

I also tried one evaluation on 10 times larger data, and the differences were then even more pronounced.

---

#### Code for the timing:

```
v = 1:1e7
n1 = 10^3
n2 = n1 * 10

set.seed(1)
dt1_0 = data.table(x = sample(v, n1))
dt2_0 = data.table(x = sample(v, n2))

setorder(dt1_0, x)
setorder(dt2_0, x)

# unique row id
dt1_0[ , id1 := 1:.N] 

# To make it easier to see which `x` values are joined in `dt1` and `dt2`
dt2_0[ , id2 := x]

bm = microbenchmark(
  
  henrik = {
    dt1 = copy(dt1_0)
    dt2 = copy(dt2_0)
    k = 2L
    d_henrik = dt1[ , {
      kn = knn(dt2$x, x, k)
      c(.SD[as.vector(row(kn$nn.idx))],
        dt2[as.vector(kn$nn.idx),
            .(id2, nr = as.vector(col(kn$nn.idx)))])
      }]
  },
  
  chinsoon = {
    
    dt1 = copy(dt1_0)
    dt2 = copy(dt2_0)
    dt1[, ID := .I]
    dt2[, rn := .I]
    
    n <- 2L
    adjacent <- dt2[dt1, on=.(x), roll="nearest", nomatch=0L, by=.EACHI,
                    c(.(ID=ID, id1=i.id1, val=i.x),
                      dt2[unique(pmin(pmax(0L, seq(x.rn-n, x.rn+n, by=1L)), .N))])][,(1L) := NULL]
    
    d_chinsoon = adjacent[order(abs(val-x)), head(.SD, n), keyby=ID]
    
  },
  
  r2evans = {
    dt1 = copy(dt1_0)
    dt2 = copy(dt2_0)
    dt1[, id2 := lapply(x, function(z) { r <- head(order(abs(z - dt2$x)), n = 2); dt2[ r, .(id2, nr = order(r)) ]; }) ]
    d_r2evans = as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(dt1, id2))
  
 },
  
  sindri = {
    dt1 = copy(dt1_0)
    dt2 = copy(dt2_0)
    n <- 2L
    sen <- 1:n
    d_sindri = dt1[ , 
                  {
                    nrank <- frank(abs(x - dt2$x), ties.method="first")
                    nearest <- which(nrank %in% sen)
                    .(x = x, id2 = dt2$id2[nearest], roll = paste0("nr", nrank[nearest]))
                  }, by = id1]
  }
  , times = 20L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
#   henrik    8.09383   10.19823   10.54504   10.2835   11.00029   13.72737    20
# chinsoon 2140.48116 2154.15559 2176.94620 2171.5824 2192.54536 2254.20244    20
#  r2evans 4496.68625 4562.03011 4677.35214 4680.0699 4751.35237 4935.10655    20
#   sindri 4194.93867 4397.76060 4406.29278 4402.7913 4432.76463 4490.82789    20
```

Check for equality, after some sorting:

```
setorder(d_henrik, x)

all.equal(d_henrik$id2, d_chinsoon$id2)
# TRUE

all.equal(d_henrik$id2, d_r2evans$id2)
# TRUE

setorder(d_sindri, x, roll)
all.equal(d_henrik$id2, d_sindri$id2)
# TRUE
```

---

#### Additional grouping variable

A quick and dirty work-around for an additional join variable; the *knn* is done by group:

```
d1 = data.table(g = 1:2, x = c(1, 5))
d2 = data.table(g = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L),
                x = c(2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 10))
d1
#    g x
# 1: 1 4
# 2: 2 4

d2
#    g  x
# 1: 1  2
# 2: 1  4 # nr 1 
# 3: 1  5 # nr 2

# 4: 2  0
# 5: 2  1 # nr 2
# 6: 2  6 # nr 1

# 7: 3 10

d1[ , {
  gg = g
  kn = knn(d2[g == gg, x], x, k)
  c(.SD[rep(seq.int(.N), k)],
    d2[g == gg][as.vector(kn$nn.idx),
                .(x2 = x, nr = rep(seq.int(k), each = d1[g == gg, .N]))]) 
}, by = g]

#    g x x2 nr
# 1: 1 4  4  1
# 2: 1 4  5  2
# 3: 2 4  6  1
# 4: 2 4  1  2
```

Comment: just curious, can I use this with multiple join columns? like in data.table, I can specify on=c("group", "x") so the join will first match by "group" and then roll to the nearest x.

Comment: I need to sleep now, will try to solve your question in my dreams (or nightmares...)

Comment: awesome @Henrik, I will still have sindri's answer as accepted for simplicity  reason with no additional library, but I will definitely check this out

Comment: Yes, just keep sindri's answer (or whichever you like), it really doesn't matter to me ;). I just added the timings as a reference for future visitors. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `distances` to *get n nearest neighbours*:

```
library(distances)

n <- 2
x <- nearest_neighbor_search(distances(c(dt2$x, dt1$x)), n
     , nrow(dt2) + seq_len(nrow(dt1)), seq_len(nrow(dt2)))
x[] <- dt2$id2[x]
x <- t(x)
colnames(x) <- paste0("nr", seq_len(n))
cbind(dt1, x)
#     x id1 nr1 nr2
#1:  15   x   a   b
#2: 101   y   c   b
```