# R: Is there a way to get unique, closest matches with the rows in the same data.table based on multiple columns?

Tags: r, data.table, matching, nearest-neighbor

In R, I want to get unique, closest matches for the rows in a data.table which are identified by unique ids based on values in two columns. Here, I provide a toy example and the code I'm using to achieve this.

```
dt <- data.table(id  = letters,
                  value_1 = as.integer(runif(26,1,20)),
                  value_2 = as.integer(runif(26,1,10)))

pairs <- data.table()
while(nrow(dt) >= 2){
  k <- dt[c(1)]
  m <- dt[-1]
  t <- m[k, roll = "nearest",on = .(value_1,value_2)]
  pairs <- rbind(pairs,t)
  dt <- dt[!dt$id %in% pairs$id & !dt$id %in% pairs$i.id]
}
pairs <- pairs[,-c(2,3)]
```

This gives me a data.table with the matched ids and the ones that do not get any matches.

```
  id   i.id
1 NA    a
2 NA    b
3 m     c
4 v     d
5 y     e
6 i     f
...
```

Is there a way to do this without the loop. I intend to implement this on a data.table with more than 20 million observations? Clearly, using a loop is extremely inefficient. I was wondering if the roll join command can be run on a copy of the main data.table by introducing an exception condition -- so as not to match the same ids with each other. Maybe something like this:

```
m <- dt
t <- m[dt, roll = "nearest",on = .(value_1,value_2)]
```

Without the exception, this command merely generates matches of ids with themselves. Also, this does not ensure unique matches.

Thanks!

Comment: Could this be a duplicate?
[please see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760320/nearest-n-rolling-join-in-r-data-table)

Comment: In case it's not ... your example is fine, but since you didn't set your random seed, we are likely to never produce the same values. Please use `set.seed(42)` or some other (notable or random) number before your data generator.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes, you're iteratively building `pairs`, which is breaking the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) chapter 2, *Growing objects*, which be absolutely *heinous* if you're looking at millions of rows, most certainly do not do that.

Comment: I think you believe that this should be an easier, *vectorizable* solution, but I believe that that is not the case, especially in terms of efficiency (though computer limitations are also a factor). You effectively want to find the closest (distance-wise) and pair rows up, halving your data size (perhaps you intend to repeat, not sure). This is a distance function, and typically when doing this all-at-once, this means that an `n`-row frame needs `n^2` distance comparisons; producing a matrix of 20M by 20M may exhaust your computer memory. Batching/looping might be your only method.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I guess, I'm left with no other option but to use brute force on this one. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, but could you use nearest neighbour matching? The FNN package is very fast, and will give you the ID of the nearest neighbour, and the distance, so you can filter out non-exact matches.